# Submit form and bypass jQuery validation submitHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Consider the following script.  After validating the script, if they changed their email, I wish to display a dialog prompting them for their password.  The server will then only update the database if the password checks out.

The problem is it results in an endless loop since the dialog button submits the form which in turn initiates the dialog.  I realize I could just not trigger the dialog if `$('#password')` is not empty, however, my actual script is more complicated, and it would be "nice" to somehow submit the form and bypass the jQuery validation submitHandler.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

```
var validator=$("#main_form").validate({
    rules: {},
    messages: {},
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        if(emailedChanged) {
            $("#dialog-password").dialog("open");
        }
        else {form.submit();}
    }
});

$('#dialog-password').dialog({
    buttons     : [
        {
            text    : 'SAVE',
            click    : function() {
                $('#password').val($(this).find('input').val());
                $('#main_form').submit();                
            }
        },
        {
            text    : 'CANCEL',
            click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
        }
    ]    
});
```

Comment: The `submitHandler` is the wrong place to be deciding if/when the form is valid, because the `submithandler` only fires upon click ***after*** the form is already considered valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could capture the click event and prevent it from submitting the form (thus preventing submitHandler from triggering). Then in the handler of the click event, you could add the desired functionality.

- Check if the email's been changed, if so, show the dialog which in turn will submit the form if the save button is clicked.
- If the email hasn't been changed, just trigger the submit event of the form.

  ```
  $("#hj").click(function (ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     if (emailedChanged) {
        $("#dialog-password").dialog("open");
     } else {
        $("#main_form").submit();
     }
  });
  ```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ku970umj/5/)

Comment: I don't understand the first solution and it doesn't appear to work (http://jsfiddle.net/ku970umj/1/), however, your second seems like the way to go.  I will test and comment.  Thank you

Comment: There aren't two solutions, there is one (two steps).

Comment: Ah, that explains it!  Will this solution first validate, and then launch the dialog?  Seems to me that it might do it in opposite order.

Comment: In theory, it should do it as you say. First, launch the dialog, and then the dialog submits the form.

Comment: @user1032531 I've been reading the documentation and checking your fiddle and what class="cancel" does is skip validation (something we're not looking for). How about this idea? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ku970umj/3/) . If it suits you I can update the answer.

Comment: Hi acontell,  Yes, this does the required functionality.  It also seems like a clean solution.

Comment: @user1032531 Hi there, I've updated the answer. I think that when you trigger the submit event, validator checks if the form is valid or not so I don't think it was necessary to perform that check in the if clause. I simply got rid of that check.

Comment: `$(this).submit()` is no good.  You'll want to submit the `form`, NOT the button.

Comment: @Sparky you were absolutely right, I modified the answer properly. I need a bit of sleep :)